# Improving the time complexity of a function that returns the index of the first occurrence of an element in a list

Tags: python, list, binary-search

**UPDATE 1 (Oct.16)**: The original code had a few logic errors which were rectified. The updated code below should now produce the correct output for all lists L, S.T they meet the criteria for a **special** list.

I am trying to decrease the running time of the following function:

The "firstrepeat" function takes in a **special** list L and an index, and produces the smallest index such that L[i] == L[j]. In other words, whatever the element at L[i] is, the "firstrepeat" function returns the index of the first occurrence of this element in the list.

---

**What is special about the list L?:**

- The list may contain repeated elements on the increasing side of the list, or the decreasing side, but not both. i.e [3,2,1,1,1,5,6] is fine but not [4,3,2,2,1,2,3]
- The list is decreasing(or staying the same) and then increasing(or staying the same).
- Examples:

  ```
  L = [4,2,0,1,3] 
  L = [3,3,3,1,0,7,8,9,9]
  L = [4,3,3,1,1,1]
  L = [1,1,1,1]
  ```

---

**Example Output:**

Say we have L = [4,3,3,1,1,1]

firstrepeat(L,2) would output 1

firstrepeat(L,5) would output 3

---

I have the following code. I believe the complexity is O(log n) or better (though I could be missing something). I am looking for ways to improve the time complexity.

```
def firstrepeat(L, i):
    left = 0
    right = i
    doubling = 1
    #A Doubling Search
    #In doubling search, we start at one index and then we look at one step 
    #forward, then two steps forward, then four steps, then 8, then 16, etc. 
    #Once we have gone too far, we do a binary search on the subset of the list 
    #between where we started and where we went to far.
    while True:
        if (right - doubling) < 0:
            left = 0
            break
        if L[i] != L[right - doubling]:
            left = right - doubling
            break
        if L[i] == L[right - doubling]:
            right = right - doubling
            doubling = doubling * 2
    #A generic Binary search
    while right - left > 1:
        median = (left + right) // 2
        if L[i] != L[median]:
            left = median
        else:
            right = median

    f L[left] == L[right]:
        return left
    else: 
        return right
```

Comment: how big are the lists we are talking about? a simple, 13-bytes long, `L.index(L[i])` seems very tempting..

Comment: Please provide correct output for `firstrepeat([4, 1, 2, 4, 4], 4)`. I believe the answer is `0`, but your code produces `3`

Comment: @soon I have updated the post. Part of what is special about the list is that elements from the decreasing side of the list can't be repeated in the increasing side of the list, and vice versa.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the list could contain tens of thousands, or even hundreds thousands of elements, so unfortunately O(n) won't suffice.

Comment: @Devon_Letendre, what about `firstrepeat([6, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 10)`? The answer should be 3, your code prints 1

Comment: Btw I do not think you need binary search here. You just need to find the start of the repeated sequence, doubling searching should do the trick. Just do not break when you are too far from the sequence, shift left pointer and reduce doubling. Playing with scale might also improve performance on real data.